# Vue - correct route, correct view, but still 404 (Not Found) error

Tags: vue.js, http-status-code-404, vue-router

I have a Vue 2.x project. One route gives me 404 (Not Found) error when redirected to it. Strange thing is that the correct view is loaded anyways. This route is set up the same way as any other routes, which have no issues. Only difference between this route and others is that this one is redirected from a `<b-button>`, while others are redirected from a `<b-link>`. Could this be a reason?

**My router index.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from 'vue-router'
import GamesDesktop from "@/components/desktopApp/GamesDesktop";
import GameDesktop from "@/components/desktopApp/GameDesktop";
import HomePage from "@/components/desktopApp/HomePage";
import GameDescription from "@/components/desktopApp/GameDescription";
import BoardGame from "@/components/desktopApp/BoardGame";
import GameRules from "@/components/desktopApp/GameRules";
import GameDashboard from "@/components/desktopApp/GameDashboard"


Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: HomePage,
    },

    {
      path: "/game-description",
      component: GameDescription,
    },

    {
      path: "/game-rules",
      component: GameRules,
    },

    {
      path: "/board-game",
      component: BoardGame,
    },

    {
      path: "/game-dashboard",
      component: GameDashboard,
    },

    {
      path: '/games',
      component: GamesDesktop,
    },

    {
      path: '/game/:id',
      component: GameDesktop,
    }]
})
```

**My Button:**

```
<b-button to="/game-dashboard"></b-button>
```

**The error:**

[image]

I know not much info from my side, but any ideas that I could explore would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your route.js file

Comment: @Amaarrockz added my router index.js

Comment: Can you try using routerLink

Comment: <router-link to="/game-dashboard"><b-button></b-button></router-link>

Comment: No need for <router-link> directly, but still tried and still same issue. <b-button> on itself supports router link generation.